# Could not install Node.js using .msi (Error 1609)

Tags: windows, installation, node.js

I'm trying to install Node.js 14.17.2 on my computer but I get the same error each time. But let me tell the full story. A few days ago, I tried to install the latest Node.js version (16.4.1) to do some tests. It went fine and then I uninstalled it. Today, I was trying to install the current LTS version of Node.js. But every time I run the installer, I get the same error again and again. Firstly, I though that there were still some files from the previous Node installation that had not been properly deleted. So I've deleted every Node and npm files I could found in Program Files, AppData and even the variable in the PATH. I tried to install again, and I get the same error again. After two hours, I've decided to reset my computer. It was the simplest solution I could find. Four hours of saving and OS reinstallation. I tried, full of hope, to install Node on my brand-new OS with absolutely nothing on it, and I get the same error as before. I can't find where is the problem and I found nobody having the same error with the Node installer.

[image: Here is the famous error I'm talking about]

Do you have any idea why this is happening? I should mention that I am using a computer that does not have English as its primary language and this error seems to refer to a system group that cannot be found. But I have never had this problem, especially on a new OS.

Thanks

Comment: if the error happens on a clean install but not an *older* version of node then the installer is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue just an hour ago.
There is an open issue about that on github:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39224

For the moment it seems as we have to wait for a new release OR install an older version. Old releases are still available through their website:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: That seems to be exactly the issue. Another workaround is to [create a user called "Authenticated Users". The user can be removed after setup.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39224#issuecomment-872950332)

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know about this. I will follow the GitHub open issue for now. Have a nice day.